# Overriding managed version 3.2.0 for bootstrap when put <dependencyManagement>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pom.xml, spring-cloud-netflix

when I put `<dependencyManagement>` getting

> Overriding managed version 3.2.0 for bootstrap in pom.xml.

override dependancies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>datatables</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
</dependency>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.testcase</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestCase2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>TestCase2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <drools.version>6.2.0.Final</drools.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>  
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>  
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>  
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
       <!-- Springboot redis -->
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
       </dependency>

     <!-- Springboot HttpSession -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--Start new Added  -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>  
     <!-- script and css plug-in -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
      <!--  <version>1.9.1</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>datatables</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId><!-- for tomcat web container-->
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <!--  Start Dependency for Actuators-->
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kie/kie-spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version><!-- 7.15.0.Final -->
        </dependency>

     <!-- End Depandency for drools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>  

    <build>  
        <plugins>  
            <plugin>  
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
            </plugin>  
        </plugins>  
    </build>  
    <repositories>  
        <repository>  
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>  
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>  
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>  
            <snapshots>  
                <enabled>true</enabled>  
            </snapshots>  
        </repository>  
        <repository>  
            <id>spring-milestones</id>  
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>  
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>  
            <snapshots>  
                <enabled>false</enabled>  
            </snapshots>  
        </repository>  
    </repositories>  
    <pluginRepositories>  
        <pluginRepository>  
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>  
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>  
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>  
            <snapshots>  
                <enabled>true</enabled>  
            </snapshots>  
        </pluginRepository>  
        <pluginRepository>  
            <id>spring-milestones</id>  
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>  
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>  
            <snapshots>  
                <enabled>false</enabled>  
            </snapshots>  
        </pluginRepository>

    </pluginRepositories>  
    <dependencyManagement>
         <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Edgware.SR5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

When i put in this dependency management:

```
<dependencyManagement>
         <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Edgware.SR5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Then getting override message `Overriding managed version 3.2.0 for bootstrap`.

Can you please suggest me the how can I maintain version spring boot with `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client`?

Getting message like this.

[image]

Comment: One of the dependencies must be brining in bootstrap webjar 3.2.0, but since you are explicitly depending on 3.3.6 it overrides that older version. This is not a problem (unless the newer version of bootstrap is causing a problem for one of your older webjars).

Comment: @Strelok which version need to use (org.webjars)? and my doubt is why override org.webjars when i am using <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> this?

Answer (score 0):

[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server) uses bootstrap (from webjars) for displaying the Eureka Status page:

[image: Eureka Status Page]

Comment: @strelok- thnks! how i can resolve override versions. as you said i am understand if i put org.springframework.cloud dependency management no need to put webjars or else how to resolve this issue?