# Spring boot-Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframew..(Version Issue)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I am getting Exception while running server .I know it is version issue of `Spring boot` and `spring-cloud`. But I am using `spring boot 1.4.2.RELEASE` and currently `spring cloud` using `Finchley.SR1`.

> What is suitable version of spring cloud with spring boot 1.4.2.RELEASE?

Getting exception below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Class;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:170)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:104)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:70)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:337)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.sarathi5.Sarathi5TestCase2Application.main(Sarathi5TestCase2Application.java:14)
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestCase2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>TestCase2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <!-- <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version> -->
        <relativePath/><!--  lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <drools.version>6.2.0.Final</drools.version><!--7.6.0.Final  -->
        <!--<spring-cloud.version></spring-cloud.version> -->
    </properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
 </dependency>
<dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
          <version>Finchley.SR1</version>
           <type>pom</type>
          <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Please help me the what is an issue?

Comment: Spring Cloud Finchley doesn't work with Spring Boot 1.4.

Comment: @M.Deinum-Thanks for quick reply! which version i need to workout?- please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved. I've updated `spring boot` dependency version from `1.4.2.RELEASE` to `1.5.19.RELEASE`. and its supporting `spring-cloud dependency management Edgware.SR5`.

**version related clear information provided Links:**

**Spring Cloud Edgware Release Notes:** 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Edgware-Release-Notes

**Spring Cloud Camden Release Notes:**
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Camden-Release-Notes

**Spring Cloud Finchley Release Notes:**
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud/wiki/spring-cloud-finchley-release-notes

> version updated, spring boot:1.5.19-RELEASE and spring
>   cloud:Edgware.SR5

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<!--        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version> -->
        <version>1.5.19.RELEASE</version>
        <!-- <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version> -->
        <relativePath/><!--  lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

**Update dependency:**

```
<dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
          <version>Edgware.SR5</version>
           <type>pom</type>
          <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

After updating this two dependencies just update maven project(right click project->maven->update) and mvn clean install.

*Issue solved.*

Answer (score 0):

Edgware.SR5 is the latest that should be compatible.

Comment: @spancergibb- Thanks for reply! I tried this version also. This version override - posted issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54437489/overriding-managed-version-3-2-0-for-bootstrap-when-put-dependencymanagement?noredirect=1#comment95695129_54437489