# Why override org.webjars when using org.springframework.cloud dependency management?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, pom.xml, spring-cloud-netflix

Why override `org.webjars` when using `org.springframework.cloud` dependency ? there is any dependency vise versa? I am confused .

**See below snippet:**

**In pom.xml file:**

*override dependencies:*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>datatables</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
</dependency>
```

when i am using below dependency:

```
<project>
......
<!-- Some dependencies -->
.....
<dependencies>
......
.......
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
         <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Edgware.SR5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


......
<!-- Some dependencies -->
.......
</project>
```

This post explained exact problem: [Overriding managed version 3.2.0 for bootstrap when put <dependencyManagement>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54437489/overriding-managed-version-3-2-0-for-bootstrap-when-put-dependencymanagement)

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding managed version 3.2.0 for bootstrap when put <dependencyManagement>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54437489/overriding-managed-version-3-2-0-for-bootstrap-when-put-dependencymanagement)

Comment: @Strelok- I am cleared version issue of spring cloud(eureka-server/eureka-client) with spring boot. But In the above post i am not clear and my problem is not solved. And I suffered one doubt why override  org.springframework.cloud dependency management to the webjars? there is any relationship? how i can solve?

Comment: Solved issue of Spring boot and spring cloud:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54441203/spring-boot-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springfr